# Accessing data with spaces in key values

Tags: javascript

So I have this rest call, which is returning this sample data.

```
var test = {
    "id": "testtset",
    "name": "sf-rg",
    "tags": {
        "Tag Set": "005",
        "User Name": "Bond"
    },
    "properties": {
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    }
},
{
    "id": "365tset",
    "name": "Test365",
    "location": "us",
    "properties": {
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    }
}

console.log(test.tags["User Name"]);
```

If I run this it will give me an error.

My object contain values for user name but not for all ID's.

Let's say if I just have one json object `console.log(test.tags["User Name"]);` this will work fine, But not for multiple data objects.

Does any one know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: is `test` an array? if so you'll need to use `test[0].tags["User Name"]`

Comment: What do you mean 'not for multiple data objects'?

Comment: What is the error? And please recheck the object you posted, it not valid (it looks like an array of object)!

Comment: Can you provide a correct `test` object ? Is this an array ? an object ? Be more specific.

Comment: dou you mean "tags" does not always exist? Maybe you have to check if  "tags" exists: if (test.tags) { console.log(test.tags["User Name"]);}

Answer (score 1):

Do it Like This.

```
var test =[
        {
        "id": "testtset",
        "name": "sf-rg",
        "tags": {
            "Tag Set": "005",
            "User Name": "Bond"
        },
        "properties": {
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "365tset",
        "name": "Test365",
        "location": "us",
        "properties": {
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
        }

    }]
console.log(test[0].tags["User Name"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Little modification to what the variable should be like ... and if you wish to get the username of first tags :

```js
var test = [{
    "id": "testtset",
    "name": "sf-rg",
    "tags": {
      "Tag Set": "005",
      "User Name": "Bond"
    },
    "properties": {
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "365tset",
    "name": "Test365",
    "location": "us",
    "properties": {
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    }
  }
];


console.log(test[0]["tags"]["User Name"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not about the space in the key name, I am assuming you have made a typo pasting your json, and you are actually getting an array back:

```
var test = 
[
  {
    "id": "testtset",
    "name": "sf-rg",
    "tags": {
        "Tag Set": "005",
        "User Name": "Bond"
    },
    "properties": {
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "365tset",
    "name": "Test365",
    "location": "us",
    "properties": {
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    }
  }
]
```

for the json above:

`console.log(test[0].tags["User Name"]);` should be fine

but

`console.log(test[1].tags["User Name"]);` will not be, as the second object has no `tags` property